# Query sometimes hangs (but can be executed in less than 4s when run in parallel)

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-13

I have a Flask API that has 2 endpoints.

When the user clicks a button, the front-end first calls a `/calculate` route, which computes an expensive query and appends the results to a table called `results`.

This table is indexed as follows:

```
 create index if not exists results_tbl_idx on results
              (customer_id, result_id, team_id, team_name, territory_name, specialty, id);
```

When `/calculate` returns, it then gets a handle to the `result_id`, and then calls a `/get_results` endpoint, which runs the following query on the `results` table:

```
with distinct_users_team_tbl as (
    select team_id,
        count(distinct id) as distinct_users_team,
        count(distinct id) filter ( where targeted_users > 0 ) as targeted_distinct_users_team
    from tam_results_14
    where result_id = 201 and customer_id = '1'
    group by team_id
),
distinct_users_territory_tbl as (
    select team_id, territory_name,
        count(distinct id) as distinct_users_territory,
        count(distinct id) filter ( where targeted_users > 0 ) as targeted_distinct_users_territory
    from tam_results_14
    where result_id = 201 and customer_id = '1'
    group by team_id, territory_name
),
distinct_users_specialty_tbl as (
    select team_id, team_name, territory_name, specialty,
        sum(tam) as tam,
        sum(sam) as sam,
        count(distinct id) as  distinct_users_specialty,
        count(distinct id) filter ( where targeted_users > 0 ) as  targeted_distinct_users_specialty
    from tam_results_14
    where result_id = 201 and customer_id = '1'
    group by team_id, team_name, territory_name, specialty
)

select *
from distinct_users_specialty_tbl
join distinct_users_team_tbl
    on distinct_users_specialty_tbl.team_id = distinct_users_team_tbl.team_id
join distinct_users_territory_tbl
    on distinct_users_specialty_tbl.team_id = distinct_users_territory_tbl.team_id
    and distinct_users_specialty_tbl.territory_name = distinct_users_territory_tbl.territory_name
```

Sometimes, just after running `/calculate`, when fetching `/get_results`, the query hangs forever.

Typically, the `/get_results` query executes in < 4s. And even while it's hanging, I can paste the exact same query that is hanging into a console and run it in < 4s.

I have checked `pg_stat_activity` and can see the query running with no `wait_event` and `state = active`.

I then checked `pg_locks` and for that `pid`, I can see:

[image: pg_locks]

## My current hunch

Is it that database hasn't finished indexing the new entries to the `results` table before I query it? But that it has finished adding items to the index by the time I paste the hung query into the terminal and run which can use the index?

Is there some way I can force the table to fully index before running the `/get_results` query? Is that even possible?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Please edit your question and tag for the version of Postgres you are using.

Comment: Inserts and index updates won’t block your query (writers don’t block readers). Your query just won’t see those records if you start the query before the transaction has committed. I also hope you aren’t dropping and recreating the index all the time?

Comment: And if you are dropping and recreating the index and you start the query before the index creation has committed, then your query is probably doing full table scans of everything --  and maybe three times, once for each CTE depending on your Postgres version -- as the index won't exist according to your query.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I am calling `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS` each time `/calculate` is called. I never explicity drop the index. In fact, if the schema changes, I just change the `results` table name to a new version (`results_v2`) for example, and then create a new index on that if it didn't exist.

Comment: If this is just a cache table and you don't care about the contents, you can create it as UNLOGGED. If the server crashes it will be truncated, but writes will be much faster.

Comment: @bobflux that is _EXACTLY_ what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an explicit

```
ANALYZE results;
```

at the end of `\calculate` so that the other function has accurate table statistics.

Comment: I ended up doing `VACUUM ANALYZE results` in the end. What's the effect if I skip `VACUUM`?

Comment: `VACUUM` is probably not necessary, and it uses way more resources.